# Error 401 when communicating via REST

Tags: java, rest, https

I have a problem with communication via REST services from one provider. Unfortunately, I get an HTTP 401 Unauthorized.

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
rest.postForObject("https://login:password@example.com/rest/", arg, responseType);
```

The request for the same data (login and password) using curl works correctly and returns an HTTP 200.

```
curl --request POST 'https://login:password@example.com/rest/' --data 'something' --head
```

In addition RestTemplate also used the jersey and HttpURLConnection, however, was the same result - error 401.

Comment: generally the authentication information goes into headers. are u sure you need to send it in url ?

Comment: Supplier API requires authentication data in this form. It doesn't support data access authentication in header.

Comment: Try running curl with the `-v` or `--trace` option to see exactly what it is sending. I suspect you'll find that curl is moving the auth data to the headers, while the rest class isn't.